# How before_filter work in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How before_filter work in rails. Suppose in ApplicationController I have following code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authorize

def authorize
    unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
      redirect_to login_url, :notice => "Please log in"
    end
  end
```

How can i control access of users so that users can only access the about pages but they can't access project page unless they are logged in.
Also when this before_filter is called or is this called automatically? I checked rails documentation but there is nothing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it is important to know is that the filters can stack. I mean, if 
WheteverController < ApplicationController
If you create a filter in the ApplicationController this will be executed before any method in your WheteverController. That is great if you want to authorize all the application with one line.

By the way, the before_filters can receive a paramenter: 
- only [:methods_affected]
- except [:methods_excluded]

Comment: So is this something like this, if there are 4 methods in WheteverController and if any of the 4 method is called my filter will be executed? That is if all 4 method is called then before filter will be executed 4 times?

Comment: Yes, one filter execution in each method invocation

Answer (score 0):

here's some explanation of filters, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

In few words, what it does, it will execute the method `authorize` before each action in the controller,  in this case, your `authorize` method will redirect to login if it isn't logged in, so it won't be able to do any action

Answer (score 0):

If you use this as you have written then `authorize` method will be executed for every request. You may check `request` object, check current controller and action, and put some conditions there.